# Unity ads don't work; they won't appear on my screen

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I just finished a tiny game and I wanted to learn how to implement ads, for fun. I won't post the game. I did what Unity was saying, I finished the monetization and I made a game object called Ads (I **did** put "andriod ID" and "iOS ID") with the following code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class InterstitialAdExample : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsLoadListener, 
IUnityAdsShowListener
{
[SerializeField] string _androidAdUnitId = "Interstitial_Android";
[SerializeField] string _iOsAdUnitId = "Interstitial_iOS";
string _adUnitId;

void Awake()
{
    // Get the Ad Unit ID for the current platform:
    _adUnitId = (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
        ? _iOsAdUnitId
        : _androidAdUnitId;
}

// Load content to the Ad Unit:
public void LoadAd()
{
    // IMPORTANT! Only load content AFTER initialization (in this example, initialization is handled in a different script).
    Debug.Log("Loading Ad: " + _adUnitId);
    Advertisement.Load(_adUnitId, this);
}

// Show the loaded content in the Ad Unit:
public void ShowAd()
{
    // Note that if the ad content wasn't previously loaded, this method will fail
    Debug.Log("Showing Ad: " + _adUnitId);
    Advertisement.Show(_adUnitId, this);
}

// Implement Load Listener and Show Listener interface methods: 
public void OnUnityAdsAdLoaded(string adUnitId)
{
    // Optionally execute code if the Ad Unit successfully loads content.
}

public void OnUnityAdsFailedToLoad(string adUnitId, UnityAdsLoadError error, string message)
{
    Debug.Log($"Error loading Ad Unit: {adUnitId} - {error.ToString()} - {message}");
    // Optionally execute code if the Ad Unit fails to load, such as attempting to try again.
}

public void OnUnityAdsShowFailure(string adUnitId, UnityAdsShowError error, string message)
{
    Debug.Log($"Error showing Ad Unit {adUnitId}: {error.ToString()} - {message}");
    // Optionally execute code if the Ad Unit fails to show, such as loading another ad.
}

public void OnUnityAdsShowStart(string adUnitId) { }
public void OnUnityAdsShowClick(string adUnitId) { }
public void OnUnityAdsShowComplete(string adUnitId, UnityAdsShowCompletionState showCompletionState) { }
}
```

I don't get any errors, but the ads don't appear and I am stuck. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you watched the videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rxpj0nmlmTw ??
They **might** help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following steps:

1.Turn on the advertising service in the project settings, as shown in the figure.

[image]

2.Import the Advertisement package in the package manager.

[image]

3.In the build settings, set the export platform to Android platform.

[image]

4. Add two buttons to the scene, one to load the ad and one to display the ad.
5. Create a new script AdsInitializer and mount it on the camera.

   ```
    [SerializeField] string _androidGameId;
    [SerializeField] string _iOsGameId;
    [SerializeField] bool _testMode = true;
    [SerializeField] bool _enablePerPlacementMode = true;
    private string _gameId;

     void Awake()
     {
        InitializeAds();
     }

      public void InitializeAds()
     {
        _gameId = (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
        ? _iOsGameId
        : _androidGameId;
        Advertisement.Initialize(_gameId, _testMode, _enablePerPlacementMode, this);
      }

      public void OnInitializationComplete()
     {
        Debug.Log("Unity Ads initialization complete.");
      } 

      public void OnInitializationFailed(UnityAdsInitializationError error, string message)
      {
         Debug.Log($"Unity Ads Initialization Failed: {error.ToString()} - {message}");
      }
   ```
6. Create a new script RewardedAdsButton, which is also mounted on the camera, specify _showAdButton as the button to display the advertisement, and add the LoadAd() method in the RewardedAdsButton script to the button to load the advertisement.

   ```
     void Awake()
    {
         // Get the Ad Unit ID for the current platform:
         _adUnitId = (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
         ? _iOsAdUnitId
         : _androidAdUnitId;

        //Disable button until ad is ready to show
        _showAdButton.interactable = false;
     }

     // Load content to the Ad Unit:
     public void LoadAd()
     {
           // IMPORTANT! Only load content AFTER initialization (in this example, initialization is handled in a different script).
          Debug.Log("Loading Ad: " + _adUnitId);
          Advertisement.Load(_adUnitId, this);
      }

     // If the ad successfully loads, add a listener to the button and enable it:
     public void OnUnityAdsAdLoaded(string adUnitId)
    {
         Debug.Log("Ad Loaded: " + adUnitId);

         if (adUnitId.Equals(_adUnitId))
        {
            // Configure the button to call the ShowAd() method when clicked:
            _showAdButton.onClick.AddListener(ShowAd);
            // Enable the button for users to click:
            _showAdButton.interactable = true;
          }
      } 

        // Implement a method to execute when the user clicks the button.
      public void ShowAd()
     {
          // Disable the button: 
         _showAdButton.interactable = false;
          // Then show the ad:
          Advertisement.Show(_adUnitId, this);
      }

         // Implement the Show Listener's OnUnityAdsShowComplete callback method to determine if the user gets a reward:
      public void OnUnityAdsShowComplete(string adUnitId, UnityAdsShowCompletionState showCompletionState)
     {
          if (adUnitId.Equals(_adUnitId) && showCompletionState.Equals(UnityAdsShowCompletionState.COMPLETED))
         {
              Debug.Log("Unity Ads Rewarded Ad Completed");
              // Grant a reward.

              // Load another ad:
              Advertisement.Load(_adUnitId, this);
          }
      }

         // Implement Load and Show Listener error callbacks:
      public void OnUnityAdsFailedToLoad(string adUnitId, UnityAdsLoadError error, string message)
      {
          Debug.Log($"Error loading Ad Unit {adUnitId}: {error.ToString()} - {message}");
         // Use the error details to determine whether to try to load another ad.
       }

       public void OnUnityAdsShowFailure(string adUnitId, UnityAdsShowError error, string message)
       {
            Debug.Log($"Error showing Ad Unit {adUnitId}: {error.ToString()} - {message}");
            // Use the error details to determine whether to try to load another ad.
        }

        public void OnUnityAdsShowStart(string adUnitId) { }
        public void OnUnityAdsShowClick(string adUnitId) { }

        void OnDestroy()
       {
          // Clean up the button listeners:
           _showAdButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        }
   ```
7. Get the game ID of Android and iOS, and click Dashboard in the service page of the project settings.

[image]

After the webpage is opened, click Monetization => ad Units to see the game IDs of Android and Apple, you need to enable them yourself.

[image]

8. Go back to Unity and enter the queried id in the AdsInitializer script on the camera.

[image]

9. Packaged into the Android emulator to run.

[image]